# Library to recognise: eyes open / closed, mouth open / closed, head movement

Tags: c, ruby, common-lisp, face-recognition

I'm writing a program that is capable of recognising the following things about a face:

- whether the eyes are opened or closed
- whether the mouth is opened or closed (and preferably, degree of openness)
- which way the face is turned (left, right, or front-on)

Rather than develop this functionality from scratch (this is *so* not my field) I'd love to be able use a third-party library.

I'm hoping to be able to run the resultant software on Linux and Windows (in that order of importance) but beggars can't be choosers :-)

An OSI-approved licence would be good, but a proprietary licence would be acceptable.

Ruby or Common Lisp bindings would be great, but a C API would also be fine.

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions (either for or against particular libraries) that provide this functionality.

*Edited to add*: The purpose of the software is to recognise signs that a baby needs feeding, and sound a gentle alarm to wake sleeping parents.  If possible, this could be a much better approach than letting the baby become hungry and start crying, then calming the baby before feeding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked out [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)?

It is an open source computer vision library with C++, C and Python interfaces. It probably does not have functions for doing exactly what you want, but containts lots of algorithms for image/video analysis that can be used to accomplish it.

Comment: That looks promising ... there's at least one project that provides Common Lisp bindings too ( https://github.com/ryepup/cl-opencv ), and an eye detection tutorial ( http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_Eye_Detection ).  I'll start with this & see where I get :-)